# Chrome extension - cookies.getAll returns nothing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

When I run the following function I get a zero for the cookie length:

```
function cookieinfo() {
    chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function(cookie) {
        console.log(cookie.length);
        allCookieInfo = "";
        for (i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie[i]));

            allCookieInfo = allCookieInfo + JSON.stringify(cookie[i]);
        }
    localStorage.allCookieInfo = allCookieInfo;
});
```

It should be finding all the cookies the user has but I'm getting nothing.

**Use:** I'm creating a chrome extension that creates a new tab for the user. I'm trying to recreate chromes new tab look and how they display the pages the users already visited.

Here is the `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "-------",
    "version": "0.1",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "content.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": ["tabs", "cookies"],
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "NewTab.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you provide the correct permissions in the manifest? Also you would be creating invalid JSON by concatenating `JSON.stringify()` results, ie you would be creating something like: `"{}{}{}{}{}"`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yeah i did add the permission to the manifest: `"permissions": ["tabs", "cookies"]` I'll try the JSON.stringyfy()

Comment: @PatrickEvans Tried JSON.stringify(cookie[0]) and i get undified. For JSON.stringify(cookie) i get [], so its empty. Am i going about this the write way, or did you mean something else?

Comment: You have to also add the url's of the sites that you want to have access to in the permissions as well, eg if you want all use [`<all_urls>`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). As for the JSON i mean if it had been working you would have been storing invalid JSON into localStorage

Comment: @PatrickEvans I am using `<all_urls>`. Since the first console.log that prints the length is returning zero then of course its just not working.

Comment: Where you have it is for your content scripts, but you didn't put one in your permissions it has to be like: `"permissions": ["tabs", "cookies","<all_urls>"],`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yeah that did the trick. Post it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to [chrome dev docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies), "To use the cookies API, you must declare the "cookies" permission in your manifest, along with host permissions for any hosts whose cookies you want to access."

So you need to add "host permissions" in manifest.json like [this example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/cookies/manifest.json)